# In Google Cloud Storage, is WritableStream documented? How to wait for upload?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Functions to transcode a video from one bucket to another. 
I have this:

```
  const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file(dstFile).createWriteStream()
```

and then I pipe ffmpeg output to it. Right now I'm returning from my GCF as soon as ffmpeg finishes, but sometimes the file doesn't exist yet. I understand that stream "emits a `finish` event" when it's complete.
I see from the docs at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createWriteStream that `createWriteStream()` returns a `WritableStream` but I can't find any docs on that object, so I don't know how to wait for the "finish" event.

Comment: Scroll down in the API docs you linked.  The example code is right there.

Comment: Yes, there's an example, but it doesn't give the API for the WritableStream object. I see there's a ".on()" method, but that's actually being applied to whatever ReadableStream.pipe() returns -- and that pipe() method isn't documented either.
I can just wing it and hope, but I like to see that I'm using things correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand how a node [Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) works, then you understand how a WritableStream works.  I think the JavaScript API docs are a bit confusing here.  Here's what the TypeScript definition of File.createWriteStream looks like:

```
createWriteStream(options?: CreateWriteStreamOptions): Writable;
```

So you can see it actually just returns a Writable, which is defined like this in node:

```
class Writable extends Stream implements NodeJS.WritableStream { ... }
```

Comment: Aha, that was the missing piece: it's modeled after (or uses) a standard Node class which is why it's not documented there. (I'm still fairly new to server-side JS so didn't know this.) Now it all makes sense. Thanks!